# How to implement random.randint for appium 'mobile': 'tap'

Tags: python, ios, mobile, automation, appium

I am trying to automate my iPad to tap different coordinate points with Appium.
I am using the command below:

```
self.driver.execute_script('mobile: tap', {x:, y:})
```

This command requires that the `x` and `y` variable be an integer, but I want to be able to randomize the numbers that could be `x` and `y` with `random.randint`, but it insist that it will only accept an integer. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what about using `round` or `math.floor/math.ceil`?

Comment: But... `random.randint` _does_ return an integer. Are you sure this is Python? `{x:, y:}` doesn't look like legal syntax to me.

Comment: Yes, this is a sample line that I have in my code: self.driver.execute_script('mobile: tap', {'x': '100', 'y':' '500'}) The link for more information can be found here http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/ios/ios-xctest-mobile-gestures/index.html#mobile-tap    I've tried doing  self.driver.execute_script('mobile: tap', {'x': random.randint(100,1000), 'y': random.randint(100,1000}) and it requires that I only give one integer for x and y.

Comment: `self.driver.execute_script('mobile: tap', {'x': random.randint(100,1000), 'y': random.randint(100,1000})` has three left parentheses and two right parentheses, so I don't think that's exactly the code you're running, because you'd get a SyntaxError, not a "can only accept integers" error. Please double check and provide the exact code you tried.